# Skip to next loop (XML parsing inside while loop)

Tags: php, parsing, web-scraping, xml-parsing, rss

I'm using the following code to parse RSS feeds in a while loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$symbol=$row['joinsymbol'];

$xml=('http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s=' . $symbol);

$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();

$xmlDoc->load($xml);

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

  $title=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $link=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('link')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $item_desc=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('description')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
  $pubDate=$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')
  ->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo 'hello' . '<br>';

}
```

The problem is that it stops looping in case the $symbol select is wrong (and the XML page is not found as consequence). How to force it to skip to next loop in case the current loop has such problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested this on my system with PHP 7.0 and PHP 7.1, but I don't see why it wouldn't work on PHP 5.x:

```
$x = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');

if ($x->length < 1) {
    // We found no items, continue to the next iteration
    continue;
}

// the rest of your script...
```

The reason it stops looping is because an error is thrown on `$x->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')` when an invalid feed is returned, since the statement `$x->item(0)` would return `null` instead of an object.